# How to read message form activemq in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

Im trying to read message from a queue using camel route and send it to a bean of message listener, but it ends with exception. am i doing some thing wrong.
I have serialized object in activemq

```
 <bean class="com.herman.cxf.incident.ReportIncidentRequestConsumer"
            id="requestConsumer" />
        <camelContext id="camelContext-32616f27-d786-4ed8-9f75-2d208cd14b40"
            trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
            <route id="report_amq">
                <from uri="activemq:queue:INCIDENT_REQUEST" />
                <to uri="bean:requestConsumer" />
            </route>
        </camelContext>
```

Message Listner Class:

```
public class ReportIncidentRequestConsumer implements MessageListener {

        Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(ReportIncidentRequestConsumer.class);

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
            _log.info("================== IM HERE IN REQUEST CONSUMER ===============");
        }

    }
```

**Excpetion:**
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload.

Comment: See the messaging/JMS examples: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples and read/study JMS messaging/Camel so more. The error is about using Java objects over JMS which is BAD design to do.

Comment: thanks alot @ClausIbsen. I will definitely look into this...

Answer (score 1):

When using camel, you don't need a MessageListener to process a message.

You can use [Processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html)  to do something to the message.

Firstly write a class which implements processor like this...

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

Then you can then easily use this inside a route by declaring the bean in Spring, say via the XML (or registering it in JNDI if that is your Registry)

```
<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.acme.MyProcessor"/>
```

And then in Camel you can do

```
from("activemq:myQueue").to("myProcessor");
```

Answer (score 1):

Skipping different ways to handle ActiveMQ in camel, your exception was thrown due to "not trusted package". ActiveMQ uses list of trusted packages which objects it can serialize/deserialize (more details: http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html).
To be able to send/receive your object you need as a ActiveMq client tell that you are trust them. Here are some examples: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-camel/src/test/resources/org/apache/activemq/camel/jms-object-message.xml